# More flexible command line parameter parser than ArgParse?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to parse a parameter like:

```
command --ethX
```

Where X is a number starting from 0. Is that possible directly with ArgParse ? As it seems not, is there a way to ask ArgParse to let the programmer deals with this parameter, but keeping the parameter like `ethX` when printing help ?

If not, is there any parser alternative in python which can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with `ArgParse` as it cannot separate real parameter and associated description, I've switched to `getopt`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`parse_known_args()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) instead of `parse()`. Do not register any `eth` argument and parse the remaining arguments yourself for such parameters.

Comment: OK but how can I keep the `--ethX` parameter in the help output ? i.e. add `--ethX` with `add_argument` but not look for this argument during parsing ?

Comment: @Kartoch: add a non-required `ethX` option? It'll be formatted like the other options; perhaps re-display help if it is used literally.